# sed, find and place after and before

Tags: sed

I have massive text with different dates and hours so i cannot use it as pattern and i was thinking if it's possible to search for 1st `,` and AFTER it print `"` & search for 2nd `,` and BEFORE it print `"`. It should look like this:

```
4,"2014-05-08 18:22:24",14718202,4,184
4,"2014-05-09 22:07:11",1278184,4,221
3,"2014-05-05 10:01:24",1238461,1,222
```

NOW looks:

```
4,2014-05-08 18:22:24,14718202,4,184
4,2014-05-09 22:07:11,1278184,4,221
3,2014-05-05 10:01:24,1238461,1,222
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very simplistic way is to replace the first and second commas as you said:

```
sed 's/,/,"/;s/,/",/2' infile
```

unless you want to match the date (assuming it's the same format on all lines):

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\ [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}\)/"&"/' infile
```

or everything between the first and second comma:

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,\)\([^,]*\)\(,.*\)/\1"\2"\3/' infile
```

Comment: The one problem w/ the first one, I think, is what happens on lines with only one comma. Probably it's not a problem that could occur in the dataset, but if it does you'll insert only the one quote.

Comment: @mikeserv - indeed, that's why I said it's very simplistic and offered some alternatives. OP should detail the particulars of the dataset. What if the line is `4,2014-05-08 18:22:24` ? Should the date still be quoted in that case (I would say yes but then, I'm not the OP) ?

Answer (score 4):

You say you want the date/time field quoted?

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} $2="\""$2"\""' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way:

```sh
sed 's/,\([^,]*\),/,"\1",/' <infile >outfile
```

That won't work on any line without at least two commas - so it will skip completely any line which does not have at least the two. And it will always get only the first two occurring commas - because basic regexp patterns are applied based on the *leftmost longest* rule - which is to say that a match is always made as *soon* as possible and for as *long* as possible. In other words, the first comma found on a line will satisfy the first for which we search, and the very next will always be the one that immediately follows the longest sequence of not-comma characters between them.

```sh
sed 's/,\([^,]*\),/,"\1",/
' <<\IN
4,2014-05-08 18:22:24,14718202,4,184
4,2014-05-09 22:07:11,1278184,4,221
3,2014-05-05 10:01:24,1238461,1,222
IN
```

It matches the first comma, followed immediately by `[^,]*` zero-or-more`*` characters which are `[^` not `,]*` commas, followed immediately by one more comma. It `\(`groups`\)` the not-comma matches in a sub-expression, and `\1` back-references that first *(and here only)* match-group in the right-hand replacement field of the `s///`ubstitution statement. The commas get replaced out-right with a comma `,"` and a quote and a quote `",` and a comma, but the back-referenced group replaces itself. And so...

#### OUTPUT

```sh
4,"2014-05-08 18:22:24",14718202,4,184
4,"2014-05-09 22:07:11",1278184,4,221
3,"2014-05-05 10:01:24",1238461,1,222
```

Or you could do...

```sh
sed '/,.*,/s/[^,]*/"&"/2' <infile >outfile
```

That makes the `s///`ubstitution conditional - because the substitution used here could otherwise apply to a line matching only one comma - in which case it would quote everything beyond it. In order to ensure the substitution only applies to lines matching at least two commas, we explicitly `/,.*,/` address only lines which match at least one comma followed by zero-or-more`*` `.`chars of any kind and at least one more comma, and then only on those lines do we `s///`ubstitute the 2cd match for `[^,]*` zero-or-more`*` not-commas with `&`itself surrounded by `"` your quotes.

It would still get the right field even if the first character on a line were a comma, like:

```sh
sed '/,.*,/s/[^,]*/"&"/2' <<\IN
,2014-05-05 10:01:24,1238461,1,222
IN
```

...which prints...

```sh
,"2014-05-05 10:01:24",1238461,1,222
```

...because the first match for zero-or-more not-comma characters is the zero-length string occurring before the first comma.

Comment: thank you for explanation, it's very annoying with all this characters, hard to understand..

Comment: @ticket I could do it a little better, maybe.

Comment: If you have time and will it would be nice not only for me but also for community. I mean, i would read :)

Comment: @ticket is that better?

Comment: wow, much better, i'm impressed, i think i understood but what if we want to address lines with match at least two commas or more? what then?

Comment: @ticket - both regexps *only* match lines which contain at least two commas - neither one will affect any line with 1 or 0 commas. The first can't because it explicitly matches `s/,...,/` - so it can't substitute unless it finds both commas. The second can't because it is a function of the address `/,.*,/` which can only apply if two or more commas are found.

Comment: i also have records like : `4,05/08/2014 18:22:24,14718202,4,184` and would wanted something like this : `4,-05,-08,"2014,18:22:24",14718202,4,184` for sql insertation after `IFS=', '` should look like: `4 "2014-05-08 18:22:24" 14718202 4 184` what has to be done? isn't so simple as i thought it should be but i'm learning

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = ","} { print $1, "\"" $2 "\"", $3, $4, $5 }' looks.txt > out.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `sed` way:

```
$ sed -n 's/\(\([0-9]\|-\)* \([0-9]\|:\)*\)/\"\1\"/p' file.txt
4,"2014-05-08 18:22:24",14718202,4,184
4,"2014-05-09 22:07:11",1278184,4,221
3,"2014-05-05 10:01:24",1238461,1,222
```

This would work too:

```
sed -n 's/\(.* \([0-9]\|:\)*\)/\"\1\"/p' file.txt
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, i used it but is not working in my code, am i missing something ? `sed -e 's/,\(\([0-9]\|-\)\+ \([0-9]\|:\)\+\),/,\"\1\",/' -n -e 's:/:-:g' -e ""$i"p" $data`

Comment: @ticket: Whats the output?

Comment: as it was before: `4,2014-05-08 18:22:24,14718202,4,184` i'm confused..

Comment: @ticket: Thats because you don't have any `/` in any line, you are trying to replace it and print....try what i have given `sed -n 's/\(\([0-9]\|-\)* \([0-9]\|:\)*\)/\"\1\"/p' file.txt`

Comment: it's not about that your code is not working, i mean i wanted to combine it  with my code. Thank you very much i appreciate your effort but i think someone below posted beautiful solution, no offence.

Comment: @ticket: Nothing taken..the most important thing is that your problem is solved.. :)